# Haskell Type Inference Compilation Speed

Tags: haskell

How much does not explicitly declaring types in Haskell affect the compilation speed?

For example:

```
f x y = x + y

-- versus

f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y = x + y
```

Edit: It looks like the wording if of my question appears to sound as if I am asking whether removing the types would make it faster.  What I meant is if it makes it *slower*.  This is because the compiler has to now figure out what type it will use without the developer's help.

Comment: Presence of type annotation doesn't mean that the compiler will skip type checking. It will still typecheck, and the check that your annotation doesn't contradict its results.

Comment: You can construct horrible cases but I've not heard of a real world experience where there was an observable difference.  That might be because most of what you do will have signatures "very close" such as for prelude functions or require signatures to remove ambiguities.

Comment: The only situations in which I've seen significant difference is in the presence of large amounts of type variables, in particular when working with lenses which liberally use higher rank types. For typical programs this isn't a concern at all. If type checking performance is a concern, I suggest you ask about programs for which you've experienced it to be a concern.

Comment: Also be aware that sometimes you need the signature to be present, e.g. when working with Rank-2-types.

Comment: Note that your two `f`s here are *not* the same. The former has signature `Num a => a -> a -> a`, so it can work with any `Num` type.

Comment: This is way to broad to answer, beyond saying "it can affect it a lot, or not at all". I've seen cases where partial type signatures are _much_ worse than no type signature. I've also seen cases where no type signature was much worse than partial or full type signature. It really depends on the types.

Comment: I *believe* that the major source of possible difference in speed is that if you write a type signature different than what GHC would infer (either more or less general), then it may take a different amount of time to check *other* uses the thing with that type (because it's different). For the binding where you wrote the signature it still has to figure out whether your type is consistent with the code, which usually involves the same analysis it would do anyway if it could compile either with or without the signature. It's not that omitting the signature leaves the compiler with "more work".

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, adding a type signature doesn't allow the compiler to skip type checking; it will still check that your type signature matches the code.

And removing a type signature doesn't turn off type checking either; the compiler will *still* check your code for type errors.

So, really, whether you write a type signature will *usually* have almost no effect on compilation time at all. (It *may* have a significant effect on runtime performance, but it generally won't affect compilation time at all.)

*Usually* type checking is a fairly negligible portion of compilation time anyway; typically parsing, loading module interfaces, and linking take way longer.

(Of course, there are people who do truly crazy things with the type system, which may make compilation vastly slower. But for beginner Haskell stuff, it's unlikely to matter.)

Answer (score -3):

Does the compiler take longer if it has to infer the types? **Yes.**

Can you easily tell what is the magnitude of that delay? **No** , but it certainly is not small.

The inference engine is very complex, and not many people touch it. The best person in the world you can ask this question is Dr. Simon Peyton Jones.

Comment: In other cases, it may take longer if it has to check the type signature. Type inference is *usually* pretty snappy in practice.